# Sum of records in property list

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist, nsdictionary

How can I calculate the sum of all numbers in all dictionaries for the key for example "Hours"?

Couldn't find any informations about that.

Here is piece of my property list I'm talking about:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Address1</key>
        <string>17 Stanley Road</string>
        <key>Address2</key>
        <string>Essex</string>
        <key>City</key>
        <string>Southend On Sea</string>
        <key>Email</key>
        <string>lmozdzen@gmail.com</string>
        <key>Lessons</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>LessonComment</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>LessonDate</key>
                <string>05/06/2013</string>
                <key>LessonHomework</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>LessonHours</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>LessonNext</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>LessonNumber</key>
                <string>1</string>
                <key>LessonTime</key>
                <string></string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>LessonComment</key>
                <string>Ryun</string>
                <key>LessonDate</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>LessonHomework</key>
                <string>T</string>
                <key>LessonHours</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>LessonNext</key>
                <string>Ty</string>
                <key>LessonNumber</key>
                <string>4</string>
                <key>LessonTime</key>
                <string></string>
            </dict>
        </array>
```

I want the sum of all numbers for key "LessonHours"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html):

```
NSNumber *sum = [[yourDict allKeys] valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.theIntegerPropertyToSum"];
```

Or you can use plane old style addition using loop.

```
NSInteger sum=0;
for(NSString *string in yourDict){
    sum+=[string integerValue];
}
```

Comment: I have array which contains dictionaries with NSNumbers for key "Hours".

Comment: you must post complete question. And i think you should try from my answer this is a hint..

Comment: @LukaszMozdzen Please read the answer a little closer - `theIntegerPropertyToSum` is the property to sum. If your property is called `Hours`, you can just substitute that yourself. Anoop's answer when written this way is more general and more likely to help other users in the future.

Comment: I did but: self.lessons = [self.pupilDict valueForKey:@"Lessons"]; NSNumber *sum = [[self.lessons allKeys] valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.LessonHours"];  is giving me error: "No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'allKeys'"

Comment: @LukaszMozdzen: if it is array, dont use `allKeys`. Simply try `[self.lessons vFKPath.....`

Comment: I knew I couldn't use array but didn't know how to sorted. Taking off allKeys solved it. Thanks a lot