# Filter NSDictionary of NSDictionaries using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I want to sum all sizes of images that can be downloaded from my server and not yet exist in my App. I have the following Dictionary containing other dictionaries:

```
    "iPhone_small_991.jpg" =     {
        PictureExists = 1;
        PictureSize = 2406;
    };
    "iPhone_small_992.jpg" =     {
        PictureExists = 0;
        PictureSize = 2384;
    };
    "iPhone_small_993@2x.jpg" =     {
        PictureExists = 1;
        PictureSize = 2642;
    };
```

How does a NSPredicate have to look like if I want to get an array of all objects that match a certain key pattern (ENDSWITH @2x.jpg and PictureExists = 0) ??

Best solution would be to calculate the sum directly :)

Comment: You can add by using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029616/sum-of-records-in-property-list/17029643#17029643

Comment: It is faster to just iterate all keys rather than using *NSPredicate*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get `allKeys` from the dictionary, then filter that array using the `ENDSWITH @2x.jpg` predicate. Then you can use `objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:` to get the matching dictionaries. Then filter that array using the `PictureExists = 0` predicate. Then use `KVC` to get the `@sum.PictureSize`.

Answer (score 3):

Two steps:

1. filter the `NSDictionary` with a `NSPredicate`, getting the array of keys matching the desired pattern

   ```
   NSArray *matchingKeys = [[d allKeys] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"name ENDSWITH[cd] @@2x"]];
   ```
2. sum up the `PictureSize` values using [KVC collection operators](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/)

   ```
   [[d objectsForKeys:matchingKeys notFoundMarker:NSNull.null] valueForKey:@"@sum.PictureSize"];
   ```